# How should I approach "has many through" relationships with Single Table Inheritance (STI) in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance

I have a parent class called Place.

```
# Parent class for Country, City and District
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Country < Place
  has_many :cities, foreign_key: "parent_id"
  has_many :districts, through: :cities
end

class City < Place
  belongs_to :country, foreign_key: "parent_id"
  has_many :districts, foreign_key: "parent_id"
end

class District < Place
  belongs_to :city, foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  has_one :country, through: :city
end
```

The schema:

```
create_table "places", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "type"
  t.integer  "parent_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "places", ["parent_id"], name: "index_places_on_parent_id"
add_index "places", ["type"], name: "index_places_on_type"
```

The following works as expected:

```
@country.cities # => Returns all of the cities that belong to this country
@city.districts # => Returns all of the districts that belong to this city
```

But this does not work as I thought it would:

```
@country.districts # => Does not return all of the districts belonging to cities in this country
```

Can anybody explain how I should approach has many through with STIs?

### Update

Here's the output SQL query from `@country.districts`

```
SELECT "places".* FROM "places" INNER JOIN "places" "cities_districts_join" ON "places"."parent_id" = "cities_districts_join"."id" WHERE "places"."type" IN ('City') AND "places"."type" IN ('District') AND "cities_districts_join"."parent_id" = ?  [["parent_id", 1]]
```

I think the problem is that it's using the same join table for both relations, but I'm not sure if there's a "Rails way" to change the name of the joins table (elegantly)

Comment: what does it show in query log when you run `@country.districts` ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the SQL output

Comment: Your setup looks kind of non-standard to me. What's your reasoning for using STI here?

Comment: I have 3 models, all of which have the exact same table structure. I chose STI to cut the duplication there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a challenging case for ActiveRecord. It needs to infer that columns in the self-join needed to find `districts` are STI instances.  Apparently it's not smart enough to get this right. Since the only table is `places`, it's not much of a surprise that it generates this query:

```
SELECT "places".* FROM "places" 
INNER JOIN "places" "cities_districts_join" 
ON "places"."parent_id" = "cities_districts_join"."id" 
WHERE "places"."type" IN ('City')   <<<<< ERROR HERE
AND "places"."type" IN ('District') 
AND "cities_districts_join"."parent_id" = ?
```

As you can see the type check must fail since one string can't be both `City` and `District`.  All would work if the first clause in the `WHERE` were instead

```
WHERE "cities_districts_join"."type" IN ('City')
```

I tried several options on the relations (thought `:class_name` might do it), but no joy.

You can work around this limitation with SQL.  Delete the `has_many ... through` in the `Country` class and replace with

```
def districts
  District.find_by_sql(['SELECT * from places AS city 
                           INNER JOIN places AS district 
                         ON district.parent_id = city.id 
                         WHERE city.parent_id = ?', id])
end
```

Or maybe someone else will see a more elegant way.  If not, you might consider posting this as an issue in Rails development.  It's an interesting case.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this, @Gene. This was the conclusion I came to too. I was really hoping there would be some quick and elegant way around this in rails, like a `:join_as` option or something... I'll speak to the Rails core team - could be interesting to add.

Comment: @bodacious Be of good cheer. I've run into a few things like this: where a current version of Rails has a limitation or bug that can be fixed with raw SQL, then replaced by something more elegant when the next Rails version plugs the hole.

Comment: Yep - I think it will be fun to add :)

Comment: Added this as an issue on the Rails Github account https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12474

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change the inheritance of your models.

```
class Country < Place

class City < Country

class District < City
```

And then remove the

```
has_one :country through: :city
```

line.

Scroll down to find info about STI
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: Thanks Stuart, but logically that inheritance structure doesn't make sense... Country, City and District are all a type of Place. But a District isn't a type of City

Comment: Correct. But they inherit the the Place type through each inheritance, it's just a more specific Place. Here's a link that was in the STI section of my previous link: http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html